# How to change the "both added" and "both modified" colors during a Git merge in Git Bash

Tags: git

I find the red text of the "both added" and "both modified" file statuses very hard to read on Git Bash. Is there a way to change the color scheme of these to something more readable. I know you can change the color for some other Git options, but I've been unable to find this particular option. Thanks!

Comment: you can find how to do it here http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration

Comment: I don't see the setting for the particular statuses I'm looking for on that page.

Comment: Which one are you looking for? For git status it's `added | changed | untracked | deleted`. You can modify it just as told in the link ( for example `color.status.added` or modify your `gitconfig` file adding `[color "status"]` section.

Comment: Probably you want to change the color configuration for the terminal you are using, instead of for `git`. `git` just says "make this red", but the terminal is what decides what exactly "red" looks like...

Comment: @kaman, I'm not sure if this is Git's name for it, but I'm looking for the "both modified" and "both added" statuses that you get when you have merge conflicts. I merged master into my feature branch and had a status that said "Both modified: /path/to/file". I already have color modifications for untracked and changed, and neither of them influenced the color of this "Both modified" status.

Comment: All unmerged data is printed in red color by default and you can't change it (at least not through config file because i guess you are not interested in poking with git source code)

Comment: Huh. That's surprising. Any ideas for changing it outside of gitconfig?

Comment: You can download the sources and change the `WT_STATUS_UNMERGED` color to a different one in `wt-status.c` file if you like.