# colorize unmerged changes (e.g., files with "both modified" status) after git merge

Tags: git

The same questions was asked three years ago in

[How to change the "both added" and "both modified" colors during a Git merge in Git Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24679539/8107095)

Since it seems that additional flexibility in non-default coloring is underway, from the comment by @VonC on colorizing branch info in git status

[Color full line of git status -s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29423742/color-full-line-of-git-status-s)

I was wondering if modifying the source code, as opposed to the config file (or some other alternative), is still the only possibility to colorize unmerged material.